# Python 3.5.2 Regex in List comprehension returns all entries - inconsistent with other example

Tags: regex, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I am searching a list for a particular entry. The entry is digits followed by oblique (one or many times).

If I put an example into a string and use re.match() I get the result.

If I put the string into a list and loop through I get a result from re.match()

If I try to get the index using list comprehension I get all the list indexes returned.

Using a different list I get the correct result.

Why is the list comprehension for my regex not just returning [2] as the control list does?

Example code:

```
import re
import sys
from datetime import datetime
rxco = re.compile
rx = {}

#String
s = r'140/154/011/002'

#String in a list
l = ['abc', 'XX123 SHDJ FFFF', s, 'unknown', 'TTL/4/5/6', 'ORD/123']

#Regex to get what I am interested in
rx['ls_pax_split'] = rxco(r'\s?((\d+\/?)*)') 

#For loop returns matches and misses
for i in l:
    m = re.match(rx['ls_pax_split'], i)
    print(m)

#List Comprehension returns ALL entries - NOT EXPECTED
idx = [i for i, item in enumerate(l) if re.match(rx['ls_pax_split'], item)]
print(idx)

#Control Comprehension returns - AS EXPECTED
fruit_list = ['raspberry', 'apple', 'strawberry']
berry_idx = [i for i, item in enumerate(fruit_list) if re.match('rasp', item)]
print(berry_idx)
```

Answer (score 0):

`re.match(rx['ls_pax_split'], item)` is returning a match object each time it runs, whereas `re.match('rasp', item)` is not. Therefore, the result of `re.match(rx['ls_pax_split'], item)` is always truthy.

Try adding `.group(0)` to the end of line 22 to get the string that matched the regular expression, or an empty string (i.e. a falsey value) if there was no match.

Like this:

```py
idx = [i for i, item in enumerate(l) if re.match(rx['ls_pax_split'], item).group(0)]
```

**EDIT**

While the above will solve this problem, there may be a better way to avoid the hassle of dealing with `.group`. The regular expression `(\d+\/?)*` will match `(\d+\/?)` zero or more times, meaning that it is generating a lot of false positives where it detects exactly zero matches and therefore returns a match. Changing this to `(\d+\/?)+` would solve it for this example by looking for one or more `(\d+\/?)`.

Comment: Thanks. Knew it had to be something along those lines but I don't understand why my example is returning an object and the control is not. Surely I am passing exactly the same things to the same thing i.e. a regex and a string to re,match(). Can you tell me the difference?

Comment: I thought it was the difference between the string regex and the compiled regex, but that turned out not to be the case. Instead, it looks like it is the `(\d+\/?)*` in your regular expression. That matches `(\d+\/?)` zero or more times. In the cases where you didn't want a match, that matched it zero times. I think you may want `(\d+\/?)+` for one or more times. I'll update my answer